# .NET: Control Invoke() in Reflector

Tags: .net, multithreading, invoke, .net-reflector

So, I was getting back into some .NET programming, and through a new feature in VS.NET 2010, it detected a case where I was trying to modify a control from a thread that didn't create that control, and pointed me to an article on MSDN about how you do this correctly...

```
' HOW TO WRITE TO A FORM CONTROL FROM A THREAD THAT DIDN'T CREATE THE CONTROL
' ===========================================================================
' Say you need to write to a UI text box that logs stuff...
Delegate Sub WriteLogDelegate(ByVal [text] As String)
Private Sub WriteLog(ByVal [text] As String)
    If Me.rtfLog.InvokeRequired Then
        ' We are not in the same thread!
        ' Create new WriteLogDelegate and invoke it on the same thread
        Dim d As New WriteLogDelegate(AddressOf WriteLog)
        Me.rtfLog.Invoke(d, New Object() {[text]})
    Else
        ' We are totally in the same thread...
        ' Call AppendText like normal!
        Me.rtfLog.AppendText([text])
    End If
End Sub
```

And i was so excited because i have been puzzled by how to do this for like 5 years because previous versions of vs.net didn't flag this since i was an undergrad on a project and...

Umm... Sorry bout that.  Composure regained.  Anyway, now that I know this bit of .NET-fu, I'd like to learn more about what's going on and how it works.

**Where can I find the code for Invoke() in .NET Reflector?**

Comment: It's on System.Windows.Forms.Control. Also, I don't like caps.

Comment: There's so much unmanaged code in `WinForms` that you might not get very far with Reflector. Anyway, what exactly you would like to know about it?

Comment: ditto what they said. The code path you are interested in spans multiple namespaces and gets deep and gnarly with a quickness. What you need to know is how to use Invoke and more probably BeginInvoke

Comment: The caps were a joke - they were trying to express my excitement.  Attempt to be humorous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, let name all thing that happening in your example.

1. The code that you showing there is [cross-threading or multi-threading programing](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/threads/).(that exist from beginning of the dotnet).
2. Your **rtfLog** is using standard capabilities of InvokeRequired - this is mean, **that rtfLog is inheriting from Control class**.
   2.a. Control class is part of Winforms structure.
3. To reach the code that "' We are not in the same thread!" you need to create two or more [Threads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.aspx).

**Overall, the reflector can show you the implementation, but the idea you can find in [article](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/threads/).**
If you shure that you want to see the implementation, just compile some short code like in "code poet" answer, and look at him in [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/).(I check this part, the reflector will show you something that pretty close your original code.)

Answer (score 1):

This should be a comment but cannot code format in comments so....

If you were using c# this story could get even simpler..

```
private void WriteLog(string text)
{
  if(InvokeRequired)
  {
    BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(()=>{ WriteLog(text); }));
  }
  else
  {
    rtfLog.AppendText(text);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's Control.Invoke on MSDN:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx