# Why .NET does not allow cross-thread operations?

Tags: .net, winforms, multithreading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.NET Controls:  Why aren’t all calls thread-safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798812/net-controls-why-arent-all-calls-thread-safe)

This question is not about what is a cross-thread operation, and how to avoid it, but why internal mechanics of .NET framework does not allow a cross-thread operation.

I can`t understand why a SerialPort DataReceived event cannot update a simple text box on my form and why using delegates this is possible?

Comment: @ChrisF: nothing "possible" about it.

Comment: @Richard - the comment is added automatically when the first person flags the question as a duplicate. It's replaced by an edit to the body of the question once it's actually been closed.

Comment: @ChrisF: hadn't noticed that before... (but still applies :-))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.NET allows cross-thread operations. But you should handle it safely. Use `Invoke` / `BeginInvoke` methods for cross-thread operations. Invoke means "Hey, text box! Please update yourself when you will have time." Here is an example of usage [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx)